# This is an interesting Graph problem to find the possible paths including some random nodes in the path

Tags: algorithm, recursion, graph, graph-theory

[image: Grapgh]

Given the graph is an example of a graph problem, where we have to find the possible combinations of nodes to include in the path.

The nodes marked with double circle are special circle which should be either included or not depending on the combination. You can match the nodes marked with _ in the path if the special node needs to be included in the path or not.

Depending on the value of K choose random special nodes and traverse through those paths and find the path distance.

I was trying to solve this using BFS and travelling sales problem but it does not work as expected. I tried to think all the possible graph options but didn't catch which graph algo will work for such problems. It is definitely a LC hard problem so any help will be appreciated. If the question is unclear let me know I can help understand it better. Thanks!

---

Edit
I was able to find the shortest distance between the nodes using BFS, but now I need to find all distances of the possible combinations of nodes including K nodes on the path.
Note: 0 -> A, 1 -> C, 2 -> F, 3 -> J (Sorry for confusion I was trying to solve randomly)
More info in the below picture:
[image]

Comment: Determining if there are ANY paths (let alone finding all of them) includes the Hamiltonian path problem as a special case.  And therefore your problem is at least NP complete.

Comment: Can you provide some more info/algo?

Comment: **What are the inputs to the algorithm?** To be specific, are the `start` and `end` nodes inputs, or does the algorithm get to choose the `start` and `end` nodes?

Comment: **What is the output from the algorithm?** To be specific, is the output a list of all paths that have `k` special nodes, or is the output just the shortest path with `k` special nodes?

Comment: So the input is a matrix which is shown as a graph in the question and from there I need to find the distance from one node to all the other nodes including K special nodes in the path. I hope that clears the question.

Comment: I have added another image which I was able to solve so far.

Answer (score 0):

To find the shortest path between two nodes, use the Dijkstra algorithm.

To find the shortest path that must include certain nodes:

```
- Set N to starting node
- LOOP
  - Use dijkstra to find closest special node to N that has not yet been reached.  
  - Set N2 to closest
  - Add path from N to N2 to total path
  - If N2 = end node
      - STOP
  - Set N to N2
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!I found the shortest path between two nodes using BFS and I have a distance matrix now. Can you share any reference article/website to find the shortest path that must include certain nodes?

Comment: My answer provides an algorithm to find the shortest path that must include certain nodes